# Exception while posting date to RESTful services when used xmlAdapter

Tags: java

I have written RESTful services which accepts and responds in json format.

I have written an xmlAdapter class when ii got an exception while passing date to the service saying "date dosent have a zero argument constructor".

The adapter class looks like this.

```
public class SqlDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
public String marshal(java.sql.Date d) {
    return d.toString();
}

public Date unmarshal(String v) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); // QueryConstants.DATE_FORMATE
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
    try {
        java.util.Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(v);
        sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(convertedDate.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sqlDate;
}
```

}

Now when I post data to the service, I get the following exception.

"Class java.util.Date can not be instantiated using a constructor with a single String argument"

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: print out 'XmlAdapter.java' and exception stack.

Comment: Why are you exposing java.sql.Date in your REST service? Use java.util.Date.

Comment: Im getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by taking the date as string in my service method and then parsing it using SimpleDateFormat.